# Mysql Stored Procedures Column Type Reference

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

In PL/SQL you can reference the type of a table column for procedure variables and arguments using the **TABLE.COLUMN_NAME%type** syntax. This makes code maintenance much easier.  Is there an equivalent of this in the mysql stored procedure language?

Where might one need this? Consider the following insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO NL_LIST (NAME, EMAIL)
    SELECT
        NAME,
        normalizeEmail(EMAIL) 
    FROM
        RAW_NL_LIST;
```

For this i would like to be able to define normalizeEmail in(roughly) the following way:

```
CREATE FUNCTION normalizeEmail(email RAW_NL_LIST.EMAIL%type)
RETURNS NL_LIST.EMAIL%type
BEGIN
... implementation here
END;
```

Comment: In what context are you referencing columns in tables?  Can you give an example of a query where you would do this?

Comment: See http://www.dba-oracle.com/plsql/t_plsql_var_const.htm for an explanation of the concept.

Comment: If you write a procedure, chances are that you need to declare a few variables. These, in turn, mostly take input from table columns. In order to ensure that the type of your variable is compatible with the supplied column value, you can use the above-mentioned syntax to declare variables base on the type of the table column. This is considered best practice when programming PL/SQL. My question was whether the same kind of thing is possible in mysql.

Comment: Oh and I obviously mean "%type" not "%rowtype". I've corrected it in the question.

Answer (score 4):

No, you cannot automatically match the type used in the table definition with the type in a stored procedure.
You will have to lookup the table definition yourself and enter the correct type.

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-procedure.html

Here it says:

```
CREATE
[DEFINER = { user | CURRENT_USER }]
PROCEDURE sp_name ([proc_parameter[,...]])
[characteristic ...] routine_body

CREATE
    [DEFINER = { user | CURRENT_USER }]
    FUNCTION sp_name ([func_parameter[,...]])
    RETURNS type
    [characteristic ...] routine_body

proc_parameter:
    [ IN | OUT | INOUT ] param_name type

func_parameter:
    param_name type

type:
    Any valid MySQL data type    <<<-- no special magic allowed

....
```